# Fetching lazy entities from JPA2 repository fails without OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.1

I have a java based config where I define database related beans as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("z.y.x")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        bean.setPackagesToScan("z.y.x");
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        bean.setJpaPropertyMap(getJpaProperties());
        return bean;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getJpaProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        map.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        map.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
        map.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        map.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
        return map;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Then in my service I fetch some data from the database

```
@Override
@Transactional
public UserDTO getUserByUsername(String username) {
    User user = userRepo.getUserByUsername(username);
    return userConverter.convert(user);
}
```

The user object has this kind of structure

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS", uniqueConstraints =
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username"}))
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    private String username;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<AccessLevel> accesses = new HashSet<>(0);
```

so notice it has *accesses* lazy property, that `userConverter` wants to turn into the DTO in `getUserByUsername` transactional method. However, when it happens then it fails with this error

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: repositories.models.User.accesses, could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session

and I have no clue why this happens.

This can be worked around by adding the following filter into web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>oemInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>oemInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

However, it seems to be a wrong fix. I want to find a proper fix to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending several hours on this issue, finally I figured it out. I had an ApplicationConfig class that had a `@ComponentScan` defined, which in its turn loaded `DatabaseConfig` file. So once I moved `@EnableJpaRepositories("z.y.x")` and `@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)` annotations to `ApplicationConfig` class, it started working fine.